# How to Open a new tab from Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, browser

I have a website build in php, in some page i show a iframe with another website link, which displays it's login screen.

Both Websites are in different domain.

Like main website : http://www.abcd.com
Iframe href : http://www.xyz.com

Now my users see a page in abcd.com where there is an iframe like 
`<iframe src="http://www.xyz.com/" style="width:688px; height:384px;"></iframe>`

Which displays the login screen of the xyz.com

Now what i want is, if users login to xyz.com another new tab should open with the homepage, after login of xyz.com and abcd.com tab should get close.

Is it possible to do with javascript or jquery, which works for all the browser including IE 7,8,9 ??

Thanks

Comment: You can not close windows/tabs that were not created with window.open. [There are hacks that work with some browsers, search stackoverflow]

Comment: okay, but is it possible to open tab the way i am thinking i explained above???

Comment: you can replace the current tab with your iframe like in my answer

Answer (score 6):

Open up a new tab

link

```
<a href="foo.html" target="_blank">linky</a>
```

pop up

```
window.open("foo.html", "_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i think i couldn't make you understand my question properly then. I know how to open a new tab in HTML and Javascript. Please read my question description once again. Sorry if i confuse you there.

Comment: The page that is to open a new window should call one of the lines above to open the new tab. As I said in the comment there is no way to close the window, especially since it is a cross domain issue.

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome and It's not working. Looks like target="_blank" not works in IFrame

Answer (score 5):

Put the following javascript code in the `<head>` tag of the homepage of xyz.com (but don't put it in the login page if you still want to keep the login page inside the iframe):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location!= self.location){
        top.location = self.location
    }
</script>
```

now, when opening the home page of xyz.com, this code will break the `<iframe>` and changes the current tab from abcd.com to the home page of xyz.com

Answer (score 2):

i dont know what you mean, but opening a new tab from iframe is just the normal code.

```
<a href="WebAdress.netdom" target="_blank"><button>Open New Tab</button></a>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is impossible on your end, you only supply a login page inside the iFrame, therefor you cant control what the "login" button actually does, it's controlled by the other website.

The other website will need to edit the action themselves and add target='_blank', but that wont happen as their users will have another tab when they login.